# subversion: how to partially commit a file?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [partial commits with subversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75809/partial-commits-with-subversion)

I have done 2 tasks in the same time frame. A file is modified by both. I will commit my working copy in 2 steps for better structure. I wish to commit the related file in both commits with related changes, using Tortoise SVN.

For now, I'll just copy the original file outside, and partially change the working copy in both commits manually.

Is there a better, perhaps semi-automatic way, like partially commiting a file using the diff tool?

Comment: Probably same question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75809/partial-commits-with-subversion

Comment: @SametAtdag right, and thanks. Using the backup feature at least makes it easier.

Answer (score 0):

I think the sad answer is "no". All approaches mentioned in the other issue is valid and basically the same. Save the file as it is now, undo some of the changes and commit, then re-add the remaining changes and commit again.

Depending on your IDE there are ways to discover these kind of edits. In intellij you can use subversions changelist feature to work on different change lists. If you try to edit a file that is changed in another change list you'll get a warning.